# I'm using symfony 3.4. and i got this error message. Something tip?

Tags: symfony

Type error:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider::__construct()
>   must be an instance of
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface, instance
>   of FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager given, called in
>   C:\projects\sonatatest\var\cache\dev\ContainerFxwq4qg\getSecurity_Authentication_Provider_Dao_MainService.php
>   on line 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/1547) seems to solve the problem.

You didn't provide the contents of your security.yml so I can't be sure, but you probably have an error in your security configuration. You can check the correct configuration [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html), but it basically comes down to the following change in your configuration (security.yml):

*Before (correct me if I'm wrong):*

```
security:
    providers:
        # ...
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager # wrong value here
```

*After:*

```
security:
    providers:
        # ...
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
```